# Can HTML link be updated by javascript using function window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some doubts about a page:

I browsing on this page: http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/

The SEARCH button ("Buscar") is like this:

```
<form id="formSearch" class="ch-form ch-header-form" action="http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search" method="get" role="search">
<input type="text" class="search" maxlength="60" name="as_word" autocomplete="off" id="query" tabindex="1" autofocus>
<input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Buscar" id="MENU:BUSCAD" class="ch-btn ch-btn-small ch-btn-search" accesskey="b" tabindex="2">
```

So, the submit button will redirect to: "http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search"

But this page doesn't exist, and when we click on this link on the browser, the page redirects to "http://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/".

When I search for lista.mercadolivre... on the page, I get the following javascript:

```
homes.vars = {
nickname: "TEST",
searchUri: "http://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/",
...
```

But the question is: if the submit input is not linked with the searchUri, how this link is submitted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the method is `get` therefore, when the submit is posted, it will used the values in the input field as query strings in the uri

Comment: But where did he found the searchUri?

Comment: it gets appended to the `form` action. e.g. in the text box, if someone types `clothes` then the action will be `http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search?product=clothes` or something like that

Comment: @ashley i guess you have missed the whole point of the question. What he wants to know is : Why does the URL of the form wrapping the Search button, is different than the one that you is forwarded for after actually clicking the button.   Once you inspect the button, you will see "http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search", but once you click it, there is no redirect, and the url you are forwarded to is : "http://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/"